# Can you set UIEdgeInsets through Interface Builder?

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I want to make a stretchable button with rounded corners that don't skew. Currently I'm doing it programatically like so:

```
[self.myButton setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-button"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Is there any way to do this in IB and save me having to create outlets for all my buttons and littering my `viewDidLoad` method with calls like the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There isn't currently a way to achieve that.

You can however subclass UIButton and override `drawRect:`

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *textFieldBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"my-button.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)];
    [textFieldBackground drawInRect:[self bounds]];
}
```